# Multiple OutOfMemoryException across different app pools when plenty of memory available

Tags: .net, out-of-memory, windows-server-2019

I am trying to track down what could be causing OutOfMemoryExceptions.

Here are the facts about our setup:

- We are running about 70 .NET Framework 4.8 web applications on the same Windows 2019 server, each in their own app pool.
- The applications are running in 64-bit mode (verified in Task Manager).
- Through the day we see spates of OutOfMemoryExceptions occurring close together across different applications.
- The OutOfMemoryExceptions occur in different parts of the code.
- The overall memory usage is around 85% of the machine's capacity, and this is a big machine, i.e. the memory available is about 30-40 gigabyte. The machine tends to sit around this level of usage throughout the day (which I guess is to be expected).
- The applications experiencing errors are using anywhere between 3 to 6 gigabytes of RAM.
- Paging file is set to be automatically managed
- Private and Virtual Memory Limits on the app pools are not set (they are set to 0 according to the settings in IIS)
- We have taken memory dumps and analysed the usage in DotMemory but not seen anything particularly unexpected.

As I understand it, there are a few reasons an out-of-memory error could be occurring, but none of them make sense to me in this context.

We don't seem to have genuinely run out of memory on the machine, as we have lots of memory and plenty of page file space available.

These are modern, 64 bit applications, and most of the older issues with memory limits, such as being unable to allocate objects larger than 2 gigabytes, no longer apply.

If the issue was due to being unable to allocate enough contiguous space because of fragmentation, then we would expect to see the error correlated with larger objects first. But the behavior we are seeing is clusters of exceptions with relatively small objects (e.g. 10s to 100 MB at most).

What could be the problem be, and what other steps could we take to diagnose the issue?

Comment: Objects bigger then ~80K are allocated in the Large Objects Heap (LOH) and this heap is not being defragmented during GC. If an app operates a big amount of short living big objects it's possible that LOH will be fragmented so much, that there will not be enough contiguous space to allocate an object. If you use dotMemory, there is a help topic about needed view. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/Heap_Fragmentation.html

Comment: Thanks Ed.ward, that explanation is indeed plausible, but I don't think was the issue in our case.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that the application was actually running 32 bit mode, and therefore suffered from memory limits.

Interestingly Task Manager lied to us, and said the process was running in 64 bit mode. But inspecting the DLL using [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows) showed that it was actually running in 32 bits.

The application was set to run with "Any CPU", and was compiled and run on 64 bit machines. But we believe it was reverting to 32 bits because of an ancient package being referenced called [csharp-argon2](https://github.com/alipha/csharp-argon2/). As explained on that package's project site, specifying x64 explicitly solved the problem.